# How to print loop result in next blank page if Current Page is Full

Tags: vb.net

I have have the following codes to print the voucher, but I face problem in loop section while printing the SQL query result if the page is full it reprints using same page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD9cB.jpg)

```
Private Sub ATATprint_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles ATATprint.PrintPage

    Dim Brush1 As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
    Dim ValueBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.DarkGreen)
    Dim lblFont As Font = New Font("B Yekan", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim ValueFont As Font = New Font("Agency FB", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim ypos As Integer = 300
    Dim pn As Integer = 1

    Dim str(6) As String
    str(0) = TrnAccountType
    str(1) = TrnAccountNo
    str(2) = TrnAccountName
    str(3) = TrnCurrecy
    str(4) = TrnExRate
    str(5) = TrnAmount
    str(6) = TrnNarration
    Try
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("select case when trd_DrCr = 'Dr' then 'Debit' else 'Credit' end, 
                                            isnull(acc_Ccy, '')+'-'+Convert(nvarchar,trd_Account), acc_Name, trd_ccy, format(trd_ExRate,'#,###,###.0000'), format(trd_Amount, '#,###,###.00'), trd_Narration
                                            from TransactionDetails join Accounts on Accounts.acc_Number = TransactionDetails.trd_Account where trd_TrnRef = '" & fncTrnReference.Text & "'", connection)
        Dim table As New DataTable
        adapter.Fill(table)
        For row As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
            For col As Integer = 0 To table.Columns.Count - 1
                e.Graphics.DrawString(str(col), lblFont, Brush1, 100, ypos)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(table.Rows(row)(col).ToString, ValueFont, ValueBrush, 200, ypos)
                ypos += 15
            Next
            ypos += 30
            If ypos > 900 Then
                ypos = 200
                e.HasMorePages = True
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    e.HasMorePages = False
End Sub
```

Comment: When you set `HasMorePages` to True, you must then exit the `PrintPage` sub.  At that point, the sub will be called again and you can then resume printing for the next page.  This means that you will have to somehow keep track of what needs to be printed outside of the `PrintPage` sub.

Comment: I got what you have suggest for me, but my main problem is that I don't know where to stop the sub and where to resume it for next page, if you don't mid can you please put your suggestion in my codes

Comment: I don't know your data, but it would seem that you need to create the `row` variable and the `adapter` outside the `PrintPage` sub so they retain their values between calls to `PrintPage`.  In your `If` statement, just after you set `HasMorePages` = True, you should call `Exit Sub`

Comment: I did call Exit Sub in where you told me but the after running the print process starts from beginning again in the next page

Comment: why don't you use crystal reports for this?

Comment: That's because you're refilling the adapter from the beginning.  You need to fill the adapter outside of the `PrintPage` method and also keep track of the value of the `row` variable from your `for` loop.  When the `PrintPage` method is called again, start your `For` loop from that point.  Something like this:  `For row As Integer = savedValueFromPreviousCall`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill the adapter outside of the PrintPage method and also keep track of the value of the row variable from your for loop. When the PrintPage method is called again, start your For loop from that point.

Also, you don't need to create new SolidColorBrushes if you are using the standard colors.

Finally, be sure to dispose your Fonts when finished.  I did this in the Finally block of the code below.

This code is not tested so it may require some changes to meet your needs, but it should give you some ideas.

```
'These variables are declared outside the PrintPage method so they retain their values between calls.
Private adapter As SqlDataAdapter = Nothing
Private savedRowValue As Integer = 0
Private table As DataTable = Nothing

Private Sub ATATprint_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles ATATprint.PrintPage

    Dim Brush1 As Brushes.Black       'Use the standard brushes here.
    Dim ValueBrush Brushes.DarkGreen
    Dim lblFont As Font = New Font("B Yekan", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim ValueFont As Font = New Font("Agency FB", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim ypos As Integer = 300
    Dim pn As Integer = 1

    Dim str(6) As String
    str(0) = TrnAccountType
    str(1) = TrnAccountNo
    str(2) = TrnAccountName
    str(3) = TrnCurrecy
    str(4) = TrnExRate
    str(5) = TrnAmount
    str(6) = TrnNarration

    Try

        'Create the data adapter and fill the DataTable only on the first time the PrintPage method is called
        If adapter Is Nothing Then
            adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("select case when trd_DrCr = 'Dr' then 'Debit' else 'Credit' end, 
                                            isnull(acc_Ccy, '')+'-'+Convert(nvarchar,trd_Account), acc_Name, trd_ccy, format(trd_ExRate,'#,###,###.0000'), format(trd_Amount, '#,###,###.00'), trd_Narration
                                            from TransactionDetails join Accounts on Accounts.acc_Number = TransactionDetails.trd_Account where trd_TrnRef = '" & fncTrnReference.Text & "'", connection)
            table = New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(table)
        End If

        'Start the For loop at the saved value instead of at 0 
        For row As Integer = savedRowValue To table.Rows.Count - 1
            For col As Integer = 0 To table.Columns.Count - 1
                e.Graphics.DrawString(str(col), lblFont, Brush1, 100, ypos)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(table.Rows(row)(col).ToString, ValueFont, ValueBrush, 200, ypos)
                ypos += 15
            Next
            ypos += 30
            If ypos > 900 Then
                ypos = 200
                e.HasMorePages = True
                savedRowValue = row + 1    'Save the value of the current row
                Exit Sub     
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        lblFont.Dispose()      'Dispose of your fonts here
        ValueFont.Dispose()
    End Try

    e.HasMorePages = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much brother honestly I was trying it from last 2 days, you just make my day and I don't know how to thank you.